# How to filter NSMutableArray from another NSMutableArray using NSPredicate

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have some messages in DB, and i will get total messages from server of that user every time.
I have to compare both arrays and need to filter new messages. Each message has a unique id ie., messageId

```
NSMutableArray *arrayMessagesServer = [response objectForKey:@"messageList"];
    arrayMessagesDB=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[self getMessagesFromDB]];



    for (int i = 0; i<[arrayMessagesServer count]; i++)
    {

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"messageId == %i", [[arrayMessagesServer objectAtIndex:i] integerValue]];


        //If message not exists, saving message to DB
        if(![arrayMessagesDB filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate])
        {
            NSDictionary *dict = [arrayForMessagesInServer objectAtIndex:i];

            Messages *objMessages = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Messages" inManagedObjectContext:context];
            [objMessages setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"message"] forKey:@"messageBody"];
            [objMessages setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"messageId"] forKey:@"messageId"];
            [objMessages setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"messageType"]] forKey:@"messageType"];
        }

    }

    NSError *error1;
    if (![context save:&error1])
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem saving: %@", [error1 localizedDescription]);
    }
```

Comment: Great! Show us some code and ask a question.

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: Messages count is high around 1000, so it takes more time to get the new messages, is there any predicate to get the new messages by using those 2 arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you need to synchronize list of messages with the server and insert to database only messages that is new and is not present in database yet.

You can use IN statement. Like the following:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayMessagesServer = [response objectForKey:@"messageList"];
arrayMessagesDB = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[self getMessagesFromDB]];

// this gives you an array of identifiers (NSString? as in your model): 
NSArray *existingIdentifiers = [arrayMessagesDB valueForKey:@"messageId"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"messageId NOT IN %@", existingIdentifiers];
NSArray *newMessages = [arrayMessagesServer filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Fast and simple!

Comment: existing identifiers is not a string.then how to do this

Comment: @PalchuriSudheerKumar then what class is it? Implementation depends on concrete facts. If it is NSNumber, practically no difference

Comment: I tried your solution, but on the 4th line it is crashing, reason is *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "messageId NOT IN %@"'

Comment: @PalchuriSudheerKumar Oh, sorry. I wrote it in a hurry. Correct predicate should be 
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (messageId IN %@)", existingIdentifiers]